# Стоит ли дробить классы?

Tags: c#, классы, asp.net-web-api

Код с классом

```
public class BillModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public CurrencyModel Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Код без класса

```
public class BillModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
}
```

В CurrencyModel много полей. Будет ли это играть на производительность? Или лучше создать одну модель для отображения в гриде, а вторую для записи в базу? Стек web-api и winforms

Comment: То что вы показали не является вложенным классом

Comment: @yolosora замечание принято, исправил вопрос

Comment: Обычно разделяют на ViewModel/EditViewModel/Domain классы/ и возможно DTO (если не EF в codefirst) классы которые восстанавливаются с базы. На производительность влияние естественно имеет, в частности на маппинги между слоями Domain/DAL/View

Answer (score 0):

> Или лучше создать одну модель для отображения в гриде, а вторую для
>   записи в базу? Стек web-api и winforms

Полюбому лучше. Почитайте про патерны типо mvc и т.п.
Вложенные классы в основном используются для listeners или в колекциях как тот-же итератор(енумератор в c#).

Comment: Не понял при чем тут паттерны? У меня MVP и я в нем не наблюдал ограничений по структуре моделей.

Comment: Или лучше создать одну модель для отображения в гриде, а вторую для записи в базу? Стек web-api и winforms
С этой строки я понял, что вы не используете патерны проектирования, значит ошибся.

Answer (score 0):

В "гриде" можно ограничить количество отображаемых полей.
Классы лучше разбить, но не делать CurrencyModel вложенным, лучше его вынести.

Если будете использовать тот же Entity Framework с Code First, то с вынесенным классом получится нормально создать БД.

Класс о валюте - это отдельный, самостоятельный класс, от класса BillModel нет никаких зависимостей, а значит вложенным классом делать его смысла нету